# symfony adding widgets to sfFormObject

Tags: object, symfony1, doctrine, record

I have a form `class SomeForm extends MyObjectForm`

`MyObjectForm` is a sfFormObject form of the object `MyObject`.

I want to add a widget named `extra` to `SomeForm` but that's not a field of the object `MyObject`, and when i try to save the form i get an error:

```
500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException
Unknown record property / related component "extra" on "MyObject"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try unsetting it in SomeForm::processValues()

```
public function processValues($values) {
    unset($values['extra']);
    return $values;
}
```